# Copying an adjacent cell value only from the same row, and no other rows regardless of duplicate results from Instr Function

Tags: vba, function, row

I am having trouble knowing how to code my dilemma. Below is my current code which works extremely well for comparing **Sheet 3 Col B** with **Sheet 2 Col B**. Once a match is found between both **Col B's**, the code then copies the adjacent cells from **Sheet 3 Col A and C**, and pastes the answer into **Sheet 2 Col A and D** respectively.

```
Sub ID()
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, Sheet3 As Worksheet
    Dim isFound As Boolean: isFound = False
    Set sheet1 = Sheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = Sheets(2)
    Set Sheet3 = Sheets(3)
    Dim Sheet3ColB, Sheet2ColB As Variant
    Dim ii As Long, tt As Long, w As Long: w = 3
    Sheet3ColA = Sheet3.Range("A2:C" & Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    Sheet2ColB = sheet2.Range("B3:B" & sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For ii = LBound(Sheet2ColB) To UBound(Sheet2ColB)
        isFound = False
        For tt = LBound(Sheet3ColA) To UBound(Sheet3ColA)
            'perform case insensitive (partial) comparison
            If InStr(1, LCase(Sheet2ColB(ii, 1)), LCase(Sheet3ColA(tt, 2))) > 0 Then
                 sheet2.Cells(w, 1) = Sheet3ColA(tt, 1)
                 sheet2.Cells(w, 4) = Sheet3ColA(tt, 3)
                w = w + 1
                isFound = True
            End If
        Next
        If Not isFound Then
            sheet2.Cells(w, 2) = Sheet2ColB(ii, 1)
            w = w + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

My only issue is that my data will have some duplicates. So when the Instr function runs, it will return more than one value (only a few times at best), for the single row. But all I need is for the code to copy and paste from the row that it is comparing at that time, and nothing more - So only the information from the row in question. My suggestion would be this, but it is returning an error:

```
sheet2.Cells(w, 1) = Sheet3ColA(tt & Cells.row, 1)
sheet2.Cells(w, 4) = Sheet3ColA(tt & Cells.row, 3)
```

All I need it to do is for it to take only the data from the same row in **Sheet 3** and paste that info only into **sheet 2**, ignoring all other duplicates possible above/ below the data.

Comment: Or just a thought that you could put the row reference in the Instr function line of code? That way the comparison will be between the Sheet2 Col B range and each row for ColB Sheet 3? I don't know how to reference a varying row though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

once a match is found, no need to go further with the inner loop, so my suggestion is

```
Sub ID()
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet, sheet2 As Worksheet, Sheet3 As Worksheet
    Dim isFound As Boolean: isFound = False
    Set sheet1 = Sheets(1)
    Set sheet2 = Sheets(2)
    Set Sheet3 = Sheets(3)
    Dim Sheet3ColB, Sheet2ColB As Variant
    Dim ii As Long, tt As Long, w As Long: w = 3
    Sheet3ColA = Sheet3.Range("A2:C" & Sheet3.Cells(Sheet3.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    Sheet2ColB = sheet2.Range("B3:B" & sheet2.Cells(sheet2.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row).Value2
    For ii = LBound(Sheet2ColB) To UBound(Sheet2ColB)
        isFound = False
        For tt = LBound(Sheet3ColA) To UBound(Sheet3ColA)
            'perform case insensitive (partial) comparison
            If InStr(1, LCase(Sheet2ColB(ii, 1)), LCase(Sheet3ColA(tt, 2))) > 0 Then
                 sheet2.Cells(w, 1) = Sheet3ColA(tt, 1)
                 sheet2.Cells(w, 4) = Sheet3ColA(tt, 3)
                w = w + 1
                isFound = True
                Exit for
            End If
        Next
        If Not isFound Then
            sheet2.Cells(w, 2) = Sheet2ColB(ii, 1)
            w = w + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, works perfectly for what I wanted!